# How change the filesystem or all catalog /etc/ from RO-ReadOnly to RW?

Tags: linux

I have a question I have a RO filesystem that is readonly. What I need to change in the file fstab in order to be able to edit system files or the all /etc/ directory editing. I can edit only fstab.
 fstab file:

```
/etc # cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount pt>     <type>   <options>         <dump> <pass>
/dev/root       /              ext2     rw,noauto         0      1
proc            /proc          proc     defaults          0      0
devpts          /dev/pts       devpts   defaults,gid=5,mode=620   0      0
tmpfs           /dev/shm       tmpfs    mode=0777         0      0
tmpfs           /tmp           tmpfs    defaults          0      0
sysfs           /sys           sysfs    defaults          0      0
```

I do not know much about Linux, so I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following version and it should work independent of the contents of /etc/fstab:

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/xxxx /
```

Instead of /dev/xxxx, use whatever device is valid for your drive.